# Spring Integration Websocket and SSL

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I'm writing a fairly simple Spring Integration flow that processes some data and subsequently sends a message to a websocket that exists in my SSL enabled web server to notify clients of new data.

The initial GET request to my websocket succeeds and the application cert is sent to the server correctly. However when the second request is sent to upgrade the connection to websocket, it no longer sends the application cert and I get a 403 Forbidden server response.

Is there any special configuration in the WebSocketContainer or WebSocketClient that I need to set up to make sure my certificate is always passed to the web server? I'm using STOMP over SockJS for the client.

Comment: Did you solve this? I cannot find any example how to use SSL factory with spring websocketclient.